# Eclipse keyboard shortcut conflicts. How to associate a key binding with the plugin that added it?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

Just wondering if there is a general way (I don't particularly care how intricate or unnecessarily complicated) to find out which Eclipse plugin added which key binding. This would be very useful for me because I have shortcut conflicts, and I'd like to make a more informed decision on which binding to unbind.

The Keys dialog (Preferences > General > Keys) does a great job of listing bindings and filtering by actions, but I can't filter or sort by plugin. Some entries give hints of their plugin association. For example, [Emmet](http://emmet.io/) shortcuts list "Emmet" in the category column, and some [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) bindings do the same. However, sometimes the category for a binding simply says "Source" or "Edit" with no other clues to be found. I'd just like to know where these bindings came from.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Eclipse Search / Plug-in Search tab. Search for `org.eclipse.ui.bindings` with `Extension Point` selected in `Search For` and `Scope` set to `Workspace`. This should show you all plug-in that declare key bindings. Double clicking on an entry in the search results will open the `plugin.xml` at the extension point declaring the binding.

Note: The search uses your `Target Platform` if you have one defined - if this is not Eclipse it won't find what your want. You can always use an empty workspace without a target platform to do the search.

Comment: This is a fantastic start! To further help get me to my solution, say you were specifically looking for all the the plugins that overrided the `CMD+/` key sequence that toggles comments. Or, say you weren't explicitly looking for THAT key combo, but you were looking for the key combos that claim to "Toggle Comment," as advertised in the Command column of the Keys dialog. Might there be a sane way of doing this?